# How can I prove this equation to be concave?

Tags: convex-optimization

$$
\sqrt[w]{x_{1}^{w_{1}} x_{2}^{w_{2}} \cdots x_{n}^{w_{n}}}
$$

I am new in convex optimization, so I am confused to prove the equation. Given nonnegative parameters $w_i > 0$, $i=1, \ldots, n$ and $w = w_1 + \ldots + w_n$. Prove that the following function is concave in nonnegative $x_1, \ldots, x_n$.
Thank you for your answer and help!

Comment: The function, not the equation, is concave.

Comment: Note that you can divide each $w_i$ by $w$, making the expression just $$x_1^{w_1} x_2^{w_2} \cdots x_n^{w_n}$$ with condition $w_1 + \ldots + w_n = 1$. Now note that for each individual coordinate $x_i$, this is just $Ax_i^{w_i}$ for some $A$ constant with respect to $x_i$.